# Duplicate commits after merge with repo that has been filter-branch:ed

Tags: git, git-commit, git-filter-branch

I had to apply a filter-branch on a git repo, and for some reason there seems to have been a merge with the old hashes, which results in a tree that for each file looks like this:

```
-.  .--A--B--C-....-X--Y--Z
  \--A'-B'-C'-...-X'
```

The commit letters with a prime are duplicates of the corresponding letters, just with a different SHA1 hash.
There has been commits after the filter-branch was applied which makes it hard to redo the filter-branch (Y,Z in the graph), so my question is, is there a way to remove the duplicate commits?

Edit: updated tree layout, noticed that the two paths doesn't really share a common ancestor.

Comment: You want your history to be A-B-C-...-X-Y-Z or you want it A'-B'-C'-...-X'-Y-Z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should point a branch to the commit `Z`, and remove any branches/tags that point to any of `A'` to `X'`. Then the commit objects `A'` to `X'` become unreachable from any references such as branches and tags, but only `reflog`. And `reflog` has expiration time. They will become really unreachable objects after the `reflog` expired, for 90 days by default. And `git gc` will automatically remove these unreachable objects. You don't need to care about it, since `git` will take care automatically.

PS. All these behavior are actually configurable. Refer to http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc for detail.

**[Update]** Here're the steps to remove the unreachable commit objects.

To view the commit objects `A'` to `X'` which are only referred by `reflog`.

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs
```

Then you can use `git reflog expire` to delete the related `reflog` and make them really unreachable.

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
```

Now, you can show the unreachable objects using following command.

```
git fsck --unreachable
```

To remove these unreachable object, just run `git prune`.

```
git prune
```

You can also use `git gc` to remove these unreachable objects. It will pack objects at the same time.

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: I tried to expire them now, by using `git prune/reflog expire/gc` but they are still there. But I guess I'll just wait and hope they disappear.

Comment: @user3707356 I just added the steps to remove these `unreachable` objects manually. After these steps, you can check `.git/objects`, and they should be removed there.

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup drop a branch to point at Z. Don't make any branch point at any off A',B',C',..X' commits.

Git will take care of the rest.

Happy Gitting!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a merge in your diagram.

When you run filter-branch git will automatically make copies of all of the refs it processes into refs/original/.  You would need to delete all those refs and expire reflogs before `git gc` will nuke the original commits.